How do I set up Kafka in WSL to consume from Windows
I seem to have some issues with Kafka (maybe related to) IPV4 vs IPV6 when running in a Ubuntu distro under WSL2.
The following configuration for the kafka/config/server.properties is working only if I have disabled ipv6 for WSL.
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092

The code to create a producer (in .NET):
var config = new ProducerConfig
{
    BootstrapServers = "127.0.0.1:9092",
};

Docker cannot work with ipv6 disabled, so it's not an option.
How do I get it to work with ipv6? server.config/bootstrap servers ?

Why do you need IPv6 for local connections? Why aren't you advertising an IPv6 address? Have you seen docs on netsh port-proxy command? Do you have to use WSL2? Did kafka not work on windows for you?

advertising on the IPv6 address indeed worked ([::1]:9092)

Glad to hear, but what problem is this solving? IPv4 should work

operative word being "should". Maybe problems with hosts file, not sure.

You shouldn't be modifying hosts files with Kafka.
